# Issue with UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath with NSManagedObjects

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsmanagedobject

I'm having a really strange problem. Here is the code I have that should set my UITableViewCell text label and detail text label:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:[[recentSearches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name]];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[formatter stringFromDate:[[recentSearches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] date]]];
```

`recentSearches` is an `NSArray` of `RecentSearch` objects, which are `NSManagedObjects`. A `RecentSearch` object has two instance variables: an `NSString *name` and an `NSDate *date`;

When I try to display my table, I get blank cells, though the cells do appear. What's weirder is that when I select one, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` takes the data and transfers it to another view correctly.

Any suggestions would be really helpful. I'm pretty stumped!!

Comment: What's the cell style that you're using? Can you `NSLog` your objects in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the numberOfRowsForSection delegate method, return 10 as harcoded and 
Assign some hardcoded values and see if you are able to see any value.
If you are able to see the value in cell then the problem is at numberOfRowsForSection count you are returning.